# How can i add progress Indicator to this flutter code

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using phone authentication using firebase, here when i click verify button i want to show circular progress indicator, how can i do that?

here is my code

```
Container(
             width: verifyButton,
             child: CustomButton(msg: "verify",onTap:(){
               codeSent
                   ? AuthService().signInWithOTP(smsCode, verificationId)
                   : verifyPhone(phoneNo);
             }),
           ),

codeSent ? Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12.0, bottom: 12),
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                    offset: Offset(2, 1),
                    blurRadius: 2
                )
              ]
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter OTP'),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  this.smsCode = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          )))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onTap function, you can use Overlays

```
Overlay.of(context).insert(_yourCustomOverlayEntry)
await AuthService().yourFunction
_yourCustomOverlayEntry.remove();
```

You can initalize your _yourCustomOverlayEntry field:

```
OverlayEntry _yourCustomOverlayEntry =
      OverlayEntry(builder: (context) => YourCustomLoader(), opaque: false);
```

I personally use the flutter_spinkit to make my loader but you can also use built in CircularProgressIndicator (check flutter API)

Update:

Then you can use listeners on firebase tasks to update the progress

```
task.events.listen((event) {
  final double progress =
          event.snapshot.bytesTransferred / event.snapshot.totalByteCount;
      setState(() {
        _progress = progress;
      });
  });
```

And use double _progress in your progress indicator.

(this is one I used for uploading to firebase storage so you'd have to modify for yours, although signing in shouldn't be too long, and you might be happy with a spin loader instead of actual progess)

Comment: Was this what you were looking for? Did it work for you?